# Dynamic drawing of opacity mask

Tags: silverlight, canvas, background, mousemove

I've got two background pictures, one is blurry, the other one is the same picture, but more colorful.
The default background image is the blurry one.
When I move the cursor, I'd like to change the background image from the blurry to the colorful one,
but only in a circle around the cursor,
and when I move the cursor forward, the changed background stays where the circle around the cursor went earlier.
(like when you scratch a lottery ticket with a coin)
I think I have to handle the MouseMove event, and use the MouseEventArgs cursor position,
but I cannot go through, and I really need help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should edit your title with something more descriptive.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "I really need help".  We would normally expect you to ask specific questions.  We would not normally write your code for you (although sometimes does happen if the problem is described well enough and is interesting enough).  Edit your question so that it actually contains a question?  BTW you are right you will need to use the MouseMove event.  So if your question is "Do I need the mousemove event?" the answer is "yes".  I suspect though you have a more complex question.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try following this path:

1. Add a `Canvas` to your page, with the same size as both of your images
2. Create a clipping path in the shape of an ellipse (`<Ellipse ...>`) and position it outside of your image, in the canvas
3. Put the "blurry image" on your canvas first (below), and then the "sharp image", filling the whole canvas.
4. Let the ellipse be the clipping mask of your "sharp image" (using `Image.Clip` or `YourUIElement.Clip` (reference on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip%28VS.95%29.aspx))
5. Move your ellipse with the mouse cursor. The code might look like this (**note**: I didn't test the code):

-

```
imageCanvas.MouseMove += imageCanvas_MouseMove;

private void imageCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePosition = e.GetPosition();
    Canvas.SetTop(myEllipse, mousePosition.Y - myEllipse.ActualHeight / 2);
    Canvas.SetLeft(myEllipse, mousePosition.X - myEllipse.ActualWidth / 2);
}
```

If this works, you can increment your visual design adding animations on `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave`, etc.

Comment: The `Clip` property accepts a `Geometry` so you would have to use a `ElipseGeometry` not an `Elipse` and you'd have move the `Center` point.  Also to get the "lottery card scratching effect" you would have to use a Geometry Group and create a new elipse for each mouse position and add it to the group.  Use a NonZero fill rule.